# Sigma algebra generated by set of partitions (must be countable?)

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have looked at some questions in MSE but there are questions from me that hopefully can be made clearer.

Given a set $M$ and its subsets $A_r$ with $r\in I$ some index set, such that all $A_r$'s partition $X$. If $G$ is the set of all $A_r$'s, is the sigma-algebra generated by $G$, say denoted by $S_G$, equal to the collection $H$ of all sets that are countable unions of $A_r$'s or complements of countable unions of $A_r$'s?

The answers in some MSE threads I believe cover only the case when $I$ is countable.

Anyway, attempt:

1. I will show $H$ is a sigma-algebra. (i) The empty set should be in $H$. Is this trivial? (ii) If $X\in H$, then either $X$ is a countable union of some $A_r$'s so that $X^c\in H$ too by definition, or $X$ is a complement of countable union of some $A_r$'s so that $X^c\in H$ also by def. (iii) If $(X_n)$ is a sequence in $H$, consider $\bigcup X_n$. If all $X_n$'s are countable unions of some $A_{r_n}$'s, then $\bigcup X_n$ is in $H$ by pairwise-disjointness. If some $X_n$'s are complements of countable unions of $A_{r_n}$'s, now I am stuck. Haha.
2. Then clearly $S_G\subseteq H$.
3. I think the reverse inclusion is trivial?

I truly appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: $\emptyset$ is a countable union of elements of $G$ and $X$ is a complement of elements of $G$. If $Y_n\in H$. Note that $\bigcup_nY_n$ can be written as a disjoint union of elements of $G$. If all $Y_n$ are countable unions of elements of $G$ then so is $\bigcup_n Y_n$. If at least one $Y_n$, say $Y_0$, is the complement of a countable union of elements of $G$. Then $\bigcup_n Y_n\supset Y_0$ is also the complement of a countable union of elements of $G$. You go the complement of an element of $H$ already. So, $H$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $G$.

Comment: Conversely, if $X_n\in G$, then $X_n\in S_G$, which implies that $\bigcup_nX_n\in S_G$ and $\left(\bigcup_nX_n\right)^c\in S_G$. Therefore $H\subset S_G$.

Comment: By the way, your title seem to say that $H$ will be countable. If $G$ is infinite, and $X_n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is a sequence of different elements of it, note that for each $A\subset \mathbb{N}$, we have $\bigcup_n\in AX_n\in H$ are different elements of $H$. So, $H$ is uncountable in that case.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thx for reply. You mentioned union of $Y_n$ is also a complement of a countable union of elements of $G$. Is it because its complement is in the complement of $Y_0$ AND that it is a union of partitions?

Comment: @conditionalMethod Also, this maybe is basic, but I use the definition that says empty set and complements must be in the sigma algebra, so existence of $X$ will be automatically verified. However, doing this, I am not sure, where did we actually use the fact that all $A_r$'s generate $X$? I only know that we use their disjointness.

Comment: @conditionalMethod More like I am not sure whether $G$ must be countable or not. It looks like the proof does not need anything about that, doesn't it?

Comment: That $G$ is a partition of $X$ is used when we say that $\bigcup_nY_n$, and its complement, are disjoint unions of elements of $G$. This allows to see what you said when $Y_0$ is the complement of countably many elements of $G$. It is not needed that $G$ is countable.